# Proving that $d\theta_{fX}=df.\theta_X+\theta_X.df+d(f\theta_X)$

Tags: exterior-derivative

Let $\theta_X$ be a $1$-form. "Riemannian Geometry" by Peter Petersen, on pg 25, has the following formula:

> $$d\theta_{fX}=df.\theta_X+\theta_X.df+d(f\theta_X)$$

1. What does the dot product of two $1$-forms mean? What does $df.\theta_X$ mean?
2. Where does the formula given above come from?

Comment: can you specify which book you are referring to and which page number?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik- The question has now been edited with those details

Comment: Do you know about something called interior derivative with respect to a vector field, denoted by $i_X$??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik- Yes I do

Comment: Then check Page number 23 for the definition of $\theta_X$ and let me know if it is clear for you or not...